# Fortran runtime error for an input.dat file

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584283/getting-fortran-runtime-error-end-of-file) was asked before but my problem is different: I've been trying an old fortran code to execute with *gfortran* on my mac. The input file is not working for some reason - I don't know whether it's a shortcoming of the code or the input file. The source code and the input file are on the same directory. Here's the code:

```
C***************** M.R.T.M *********************************************
C
      IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H,O-Z)
      CHARACTER*64 FNAMEI,FNAMEO
      COMMON/L1/ C(101),DC(101),DU(101),DL(101),E(101),S1(101),S2(101) 
      COMMON/L2/ SIR(101),CX(101),S1X(101),S2X(101)
      COMMON/L3/ X(101),S3(101),S3X(101)
      COMMON/L4/ TH,ROU,COL,WFLX,CI,CS,D,K1,K2,W,K3,K4,U,KS,K5,K6,KD 
      COMMON/L5/ NEQ,IT,N,NM1,NP1
      COMMON/L6/ TPULSE,TTOTAL,TPRINT,DT,DX,GAMMA,BETA
      CHARACTER*64 USER,SOIL,SOLUTE,DATE
      REAL*8 K1,K2,K3,K4,K5,K6,KS,KD,NEQ
C
C
C------ READ  INPUT  PARAMETERS----------------
C
      WRITE(*,*) 'PLEASE ENTER USER NAME (OPTIONAL):'
      READ(*,800) USER
      WRITE(*,*) ' PLEASE ENTER NAME OF SOIL (OPTIONAL):'
      READ(*,800) SOIL
      WRITE(*,*) ' PLEASE ENTER NAME OF SOLUTE (OPTIONAL):'
      READ(*,800) SOLUTE
      WRITE(*,*) ' ENTER DATE OR OTHER IDENTIFICATION (OPTIONAL):'
      READ(*,800) DATE
      WRITE(*,*) ' '
      WRITE(*,*)
     $'--------- INPUT PARAMETERS SECTION -------------'
      WRITE(*,*) ' '
      WRITE(*,*) ' INPUT PARAMETERS CAN BE PROVIDED IN TWO WAYS; '
      WRITE(*,*) '  ENTER 1 if you wish to enter the input data using'
      WRITE(*,*) '               the keyboard (i.e. interactively) '
      WRITE(*,*) ' '
      WRITE(*,*) '     OR '
      WRITE(*,*) ' '
      WRITE(*,*) '     ENTER 2 if an input data file is to be provided '
      WRITE(*,*)
     $'       PLEASE ENTER EITHER 1 OR 2'
      READ(*,950) IFLAG
      IF(IFLAG.NE.1) THEN
      WRITE(*,'(A)') ' PLEASE ENTER NAME OF INPUT FILE?'
      WRITE(*,*) '(for example A:XX.DAT or C:UU.DAT for hard disk)'
      READ(*,'(A)') FNAMEI
      OPEN(5,FILE=FNAMEI)
C
C
      READ(5,700) TH,ROU,COL,WFLX
      READ(5,700) CI,CS,D
      READ(5,700) KD,NEQ
      READ(5,700) K1,K2,W 
      READ(5,700) K3,K4,U 
      READ(5,700) KS
      READ(5,700) K5,K6
      READ(5,750) IT
      READ(5,700) TPULSE,TTOTAL,TPRINT,DT,DX
      ELSE
C
      WRITE(*,*)
     $'PLEASE ENTER THE FOLLOWING INPUT PARAMETERS  :'
      WRITE(*,*) '  '
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (1) MOISTURE CONTENT, CM3/CM3 (TH) ='
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (Values usually less than 0.65 cm3/cm3). Enter your value NOW'
      READ(*,900) TH
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (2) BULK DENSITY, G/CM3 (ROU)  ='
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (Range of values 1.1 - 1.7 g/cm3). Enter your value NOW' 
      READ(*,900) ROU
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (3) PROFILE OR SOIL COLUMN LENGTH, CM (COL) ='
      READ(*,900) COL
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (4) WATER FLUX, CM/HOUR (WFLX) ='
      WRITE(*,*)
     $'(Range of values 0.01 - 5 cm/hr). Enter your value NOW'
      READ(*,900) WFLX
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (5) INITIAL CONCENTRATION, MG/L (CI)='
      READ(*,900) CI
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (6) APPLIED CONCENTRATION, MG/L (CS)='
      READ(*,900) CS
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (7) DISPERSION COEFFICIENT,D, CM2/HOUR (D) ='
      WRITE(*,*)
     $'(Range of values 0.1 - 1.5 cm2/hour). Enter your value NOW'
      READ(*,900) D 
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (8) DISTRIBUTION COEFFICIENT, KD (KD) =' 
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (Range of values 0 - 300 cm3/g) Enter your value NOW' 
      READ(*,900) KD
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (9) NONLINEAR FREUNDLICH PARAMETER, N (NEQ)='
      WRITE(*,*) '(Range of values 0.3 - 0.9). Enter your value NOW' 
      READ(*,900) NEQ
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (10) FORWARD RATE REACTION, K1, HR-1 (K1) ='
      WRITE(*,*) '(Range of values 0.01 - 2 hr-1). Enter your value NOW' 
      READ(*,900) K1
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (11) BACKWARD RATE REACTION, K2, HR-1 (K2) ='
      WRITE(*,*) '(Range of values 0.01 - 5 hr-1). Enter your value NOW' 
      READ(*,900) K2
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (12) NONLINEAR KINETIC PARAMETER, W, (W)='
      WRITE(*,*) '(Range of values 0.3 - 0.9). Enter your value NOW'
      READ(*,900) W 
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (13) FORWARD RATE REACTION, K3, HR-1 (K3)='
      WRITE(*,*) '(Ranges from 0.0001 - 0.1 hr-1). Enter your value NOW' 
      READ(*,900) K3
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (14) BACKWARD RATE REACTION, K4, HR-1 (K4)=' 
      WRITE(*,*) '(Ranges from 0.01 - 0.1 hr-1). Enter your value NOW'
      READ(*,900) K4
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (15) NONLINEAR KINETIC PARAMETER, U, (U) ='
      WRITE(*,*) '(Range of values 0.3 - 0.9). Enter your value NOW'
      READ (*,900) U
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (16) IRREVERSIBLE REACTION PATE,KS,HR-1 (KS) ='
      WRITE(*,*) '(Range is 0.0001 - 0.01 hr-1). Enter your value NOW' 
      READ(*,900) KS
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (17) FORWARD RATE REACTION, K5,HR-1 (K5)  ='
      WRITE(*, *) '(Range is 0.0001 - 0.01 hr-1). Enter your value NOW' 
      READ(*,900) K5
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (18) BACKWARD RATE REACTION, K6, HR-1 (K6) ='
      WRITE(*,*) '(Range is 0.001 - 0.1 hr-1). Enter your value NOW' 
      READ(*,900) K6
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (19) NUMBER OF ITERATIONS (IT) AN INTEGER (FROM 0 TO 9)' 
      READ(*,950) IT
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (20) INPUT PULSE DURATION, HOURS (TPULSE) =' 
      READ(*,900) TPULSE
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (21) TOTAL SIMULATION TIME, HOURS (TTOTAL) =' 
      READ(*,900) TTOTAL
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (22) PRINTOUT TIME DESIRED, HOURS (TPRINT) ='
      READ(*, 900) TPRINT
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (23) INCREMENTAL TIME STEP, HOURS (DT) ='
      WRITE(*,*)
     $'  A default value of DT=0.02 is given' 
      READ(*,900) DDT
      WRITE(*,*)
     $' (24) INCREMENTAL DEPTH, CM (DX)='
      WRITE(*,*)
     $'  A default value of DX=1.00 is given   ' 
      READ(*,900) DDX
      ENDIF
C
      XIN=1.00
      IF(DDX.NE.0.0) THEN 
      DX=DDX
      ELSE
      DX=XIN
      ENDIF
C
      PIN=0.02 
      IF(DDT.NE.0.0) THEN
      DT=DDT
      ELSE
      DT=PIN
      ENDIF
      WRITE(*,'(A)') 'PLEASE ENTER NAME OF THE OUTPUT FILE (FOR EXAMPLE
     *  B:ZZ.DAT)'
      READ(*,'(A)') FNAMEO
      OPEN (6,FILE=FNAMEO,STATUS='UNKNOWN')
      PV=WFLX/TH
      RS=NEQ*ROU*KD/TH
      C0=CS
C
      TIME=0.0D0
      EF=0.0D0
   5  CONTINUE
      GAMMA=DT/(2.D0*DX*DX)
      BETA=DT/DX
      IF((BETA*PV).GT.0.50D0) GO TO 7 
      IF((GAMMA*D/(BETA*PV)).LT.0.5D0) GO TO 6
      GO TO 8
   6  DX=DX/2
      GO TO 5
   7  DT=DT/2
      GO TO 5
   8  CONTINUE
      N=INT(COL/DX)
      NM1=N-1
      NM2=N-2
      NP1=N+1 
      GAMMA=DT/(2*DX*DX)
      BETA=DT/DX
C
      IF(N.LT.500) GO TO 9 
      WRITE(*,*) 'W A R N I N G'
      WRITE(*,*)
     &'Dimension of variables exceeds 500. Did you increase array sizes'
      WRITE(*,*)
     &' If not, the program will terminate abruptly (see text).'
   9  CONTINUE
C
C--- WRITE TITLE HEADING  --------------- 
      WRITE(6,800) USER 
      WRITE(6,800) SOIL 
      WRITE(6,800) SOLUTE 
      WRITE(6,800) DATE
      WRITE(6,300) TH,ROU,COL,WFLX,CI,CS,D,K1,K2,B,K3,K4,W,KS
      WRITE(6,310) K5,K6,IT,KD,NEQ
     &,TPULSE,TTOTAL,TPRINT
      WRITE(6,400) DX,DT 
C
      DO 10 I=1,NP1 
      S1(I)=0.0D0 
      S2(I)=0.0D0 
      S3(I)=0.0D0 
      SIR(I)=0.0D0 
      S1X(I)=0.0D0 
      S2X(I)=0.0D0 
      S3X(I)=0.0D0 
      CX(I)=CI 
  10  C(I)=CI 
      WRITE(*,*) '------INITIAL CONDITIONS COMPLETED --------'
C
      WRITE(*,*) '------Execution Begins Please Wait---------------'
      WRITE(*,*) '------Please Wait -------------'
      IT=IT+1
      FF=2*DX 
      NKK=INT(TPRINT/DT+0.50D0) 
      KLM=INT(TTOTAL/DT+0.50D0) 
      KK=INT(KLM/NKK+0.5D0)
C
      L=0
      SINT=TPULSE*CS*WFLX 
      DO 50 JJ=1,KK
      DO 20 LL=1,NKK 
      TT=LL*DT+(JJ-1)*TPRINT 
      IF(DABS(TT-TPULSE).LT.0.01D0) CS=0.0D0
      L=L+1
      CALL SMRTM 
      EF=C(N)+EF 
  20  CONTINUE 
      TIME=JJ*TPRINT
C
      WRITE(6,500) TIME 
      VV0=WFLX*TIME/(COL*TH)
      CC0=C(N)/C0
      WRITE(6,525) VV0,CC0
      WRITE(*, 650) TIME,VV0,CC0
      WRITE(*,*) '--------Execution Continues--------'
      WRITE(*,*) '--------Please Wait---------'
      WRITE (6, 550)
      DO 30 I=1, NP1
      DEPTH=DX*(I-1)
      SEQ=KD*C(I)**NEQ
      TOTAL=SEQ+S1(I)+S2(I)+S3(I)+SIR(I)
  30  WRITE(6,600) DEPTH, C(I),SEQ,S1(I),S2(I),S3(I),SIR(I),TOTAL 
      CALL INTEG(DX,C,X,NP1)
      TSWATR=TH*X(NP1)
C
      DO 40 I=1,NP1
  40  E(I)=C(I)**NEQ
      CALL INTEG(DX, E, X, NP1)
      TSEQ=ROU*KD*X(NP1)
      SINP=TIME*CS*WFLX
      IF(SINP.GT.SINT) SINP=SINT
      IF(CS.EQ.0.D0) SINP=SINT
C
      CALL INTEG(DX,S1,X,NP1) 
      TSKIN1=ROU*X(NP1)
C
      CALL INTEG(DX,S2,X,NP1)
      TSKIN2=ROU*X(NP1)
C
      CALL INTEG(DX,S3,X,NP1)
      TSKIN3=ROU*X(NP1)
C
      TEFFL=DT*WFLX*EF
C
      CALL INTEG(DX,SIR,X,NP1) 
      TSIR=ROU*X(NP1)
      BAL=(TEFFL+TSKIN1+TSKIN2+TSKIN3+TSIR+TSEQ+TSWATR)*100.0D0/SINP 
  50  WRITE(6,200) SINP,TSWATR,TSEQ,TSKIN1,TSKIN2,TSKIN3,TSIR,TEFFL,BAL
      CONTINUE
C
 200  FORMAT(//,2X,'S A L T    B A L A N C E:',//
     &7X, 'TOTAL INPUT SOLUTE FROM PULSE      (MG) = ',F10.4,/
     &7X, 'TOTAL SOLUTE SOIL SOLUTION PHASE   (MG) = ',F10.4,/,
     &7X, 'TOTAL SORBED IN (EQUILIB) PHASE SE (MG) = ',F10.4,/,
     &7X, 'TOTAL SORBED IN (KINETIC) PHASE S1 (MG) = ',F10.4,/,
     &7X, 'TOTAL SORBED IN (KINETIC) PHASE S2 (MG) = ',F10.4,/,
     &7X, 'TOTAL SORBED IN (KINETIC) PHASE S3 (MG) = ',F10.4,/,
     &7X, 'TOTAL SORBED IN IRREVERSIBLE PHASE (MG) = ',F10.4,/,
     &7X, 'TOTAL SORBED IN THE EFFLUENT       (MG) = ',F10.4,/,
     &7X, 'MASS BALANCE (CALC.OUTPUT/INPUT)    (%) = ',F10.4,/)
 300  FORMAT(//,
     $2X, 'INPUT PARAMETERS   :',//
     $5X,'1.  MOISTURE CONTENT, CM3/CM3            (TH) = ',F10.5,/
     $5X,'2.  BULK DENSITY, G/CM3                 (ROU) = ',F10.5,/
     $5X,'3.  COLUMN LENGTH, CM                   (COL) = ',F10.5,/
     $5X,'4.  WATER FLUX, CM/HOUR                (WFLX) = ',F10.5,/
     $5X,'5.  INITIAL CONCENTRATION, MG/L          (CI) = ',F10.5,/
     $5X,'6.  CONCEN.IN INPUT PULSE, MG/L          (CS) = ',F10.5,/
     $5X,'7.  DISPERSION COEFFICIENT, CM2/HR        (D) = ',F10.5,/
     $5X,'8.  FOWARD RATE REACTION, K1,HR-1        (K1) = ',F10.5,/
     $5X,'9.  BACKWARD RATE REACTION, K2,HR-1      (K2) = ',F10.5,/
     $4X,'10.  NONLINEAR KINETIC PARAMETER, W,      (W) = ',F10.5,/
     $4X,'11.  FORWARD RATE REACTION, K3/HR-1      (K3) = ',F10.5,/
     $4X,'12.  BACKWARD RATE REACTION, K4/HR-1     (K4) = ',F10.5,/
     $4X,'13.  NONLINEAR KINETIC PARAMETER, U,      (U) = ',F10.5,/
     $4X,'14.  IRREVERSIBLE REACTION RATE, KS/HR-1 (KS) = ',F10.5,/)
 310  FORMAT(
     $4X,'15. FORWARD RATE REACTION, K5,HR-1  (K5) = ',F10.5,/
     $4X,'16. BACKWARD RATE REACTION, K6,HR-1  (K6) = ',F10.5,/
     $4X,'17. NUMBER OF ITERATIONS             (IT) = ',I10.5,/
     $4X,'18. DISTRIBUTION COEFFICIENT FOR EQUILIBRIUM',/
     $4X,'           SORPTION, KD, CM3/G       (KD) = ',F10.5,/
     $4X,'19. NONLINEAR PARAMETER FOR EQUILIBRIRUM',/
     $4X,'           Mechanism, NEQ            (NEQ) = ',F10.5,/
     $4X,'20. INPUT PULSE DURATION, HR     (TPULSE) = ',F10.5,/
     $4X,'21. TOTAL SIMULATION TIME, HR    (TTOTAL) = ',F10.5,/
     $4X,'22. PRINTOUT TIME DESIRED,HR     (TPRINT) = ',F10.5,////)
 400  FORMAT(2X, 'THE INCREMENTS USED WERE : ',//
     $5X,'1. SIMULATION DEPTH INTERVAL, CM  (DX)=',F10.5,/
     $5X,'2. INCREMENTAL TIME STEP,HR       (DT)=',F10.5,///)
 500  FORMAT(/////////,
     $2X'S I M U L A T I O N    T I M E (HOUR) = ',F8.2/)
 525  FORMAT(
     $2X'PORE VOLUMES (V/V0) = ',F10.2,8X,'REL. CONCENTRATION (C/C0) =',
     &F8.4)
 550  FORMAT(///1H, 72(1H*)//1H, 20X, 'CONCENTRATION DISTRIBUTION',
     *//1H , 172(1H*)//1H, 2X,
     *'DEPTH  SOLUT EQUIL  KINETIC  KINETIC  KINETIC  IRREV.
     *TOTAL'/, 9X, 'CONC.', 4X,
     *'PHASE  PHASE 1  PHASE 2  PHASE 3  SINK  SORBED'/,
     *'  X       C       SE       S1      S2      S3      SIR
     *     S'//,1X
     1,'   CM  ',2X,'--MG/L--',2X,
     1'--------------------- MG/KG ---------------------'/)
 600  FORMAT(1X,F6.2,1X,F9.4,1X,F8.4,1X,F8.3,
     *1X,3(F9.3,1X),F7.3)
 650  FORMAT(/////,2X,'SIMULATIONS ARE NOW COMPLETE UP TO',///,5X,
     $'S I M U L A T I O N   T I M E  (HOUR) = ',F8.2,//2X,
     $'PORE VOLUMES (V/V0) = ',F10.2,8X,'REL CONCENTRATION (C/C0)=',
     &F8.4//)
 700  FORMAT(50X, E10.6)
 750  FORMAT(50X,I3)
 800  FORMAT(A64)
 900  FORMAT(F12.0)
 950  FORMAT(I1)
      WRITE(*,*)
      WRITE(*,*)  '------ Requested Simulations Completed ------'
      WRITE(*,*)
      WRITE(*,*) '------- MRTM TERMINATED SUCCESSFULLY -------'
      WRITE(*,*) 
      WRITE(*,*) '------- THANK YOU FOR USING MRTM --------'
      END
C
C
C     **************************************************************
C     SUBROUNTINE SMRTM GIVES A SOLUTION OF THE FINITE DIFFERENCE EQ.
C     OF THE CONVECTIVE-DISPERSION AND MULTIREACTION SYSTEM
C     ***************************************************************
C
      SUBROUTINE SMRTM
      IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
      COMMON/LI/ C(101),DC(101),DU(101),DL(101),E(101),S1(101),S2(101)
      COMMON/L2/ SIR(101),CX(101),S1X(101),S2X(101)
      COMMON/L3/ X(101) ,S3(101) ,S3X(101)
      COMMON/L4/ TH,ROU,COL,WFLX,CI,CS,D,K1,K2,W,K3,K4,U,KS,K5,K6,KD 
      COMMON/L5/ NEQ,IT,N,NM1,NP1
      COMMON/L6/ TPULSE,TTOTAL,TPRINT,DT,DX,GAMMA,BETA
      REAL*8 K1,K2,K3,K4,K5,K6,KS,KD,NEQ
C
C
      FF=2*DX
      PV=WFLX/TH
      RS=NEQ*ROU*KD/TH
      C(1)=(WFLX*FF*CS+D*TH*C(3))/(WFLX*FF+D*TH)
      DO 35 IJ=1,IT
      M=2
      DO 10 I=1,NM1
      DC(I) =1.0D0+2.D0*GAMMA*D-BETA*PV
      DU(I)=BETA*PV-GAMMA*D
      E(I)=C(M)+GAMMA*D*(C(M+1) -2.0D0*C(M) + C(M-1)) 
      DL(I)=-GAMMA*D
      M=I+2
  10  CONTINUE
      M=N
      DC(NM1)=1.D0+GAMMA*D
      E(1)=E(1)+GAMMA*D*C(1)
C
C     INCORPORATION OF NONLINEAR KINETIC AND EQUILIBRIUM PROCESSES
C     (REVERSIBLE) IN MAIN DIAGONAL ELEMENTS AND RHS VECTOR
C
      DO 20 I=1,NM1
      DC(I)=DC(I)+DT*KS/2
      R=0.0D0
      H1=0.0D0
      H2=0.0D0
      IF((C(I+1).LT.1.0D-4) .OR. (CX(I+1).LE.1.0D-4)) GO TO 15
      R =RS*(0.50D0*(C(I+1)+CX(I+1)))**(NEQ-1.0D0)
      H1=(0.50D0*(C(I+1)+CX(I+1)))**W
      H2=(0.50D0*(C(I+1)+CX(I+1)))**U
  15  DC(I)=DC(I)+R
      E(I)=E(I)-DT*(K1*H1-K2*(ROU/TH)*(S1(I+1)+S1X(I+1))/2)
     &-DT*(K3*H2-K4*(ROU/TH)*(S2(I+1)+S2X(I+1))/2)
  20  E(I)=E(I)+C(I+1)*R-DT*(KS/2)*((C(I+1)+CX(I+1))/2)
C
      CALL TRIDM(DC,DU,DL,E,NM1)
      DO 25 I=2,N
  25  CX(I)=E(I-1) 
      CX(NP1)=CX(N)
      CX(1)=C(1)
      DO 30 I=1,NP1
      H1=0.0D0
      H2=0.0D0
      IF(C(I).GT.1.0D-4) H1=((C(I)+CX(I))/2)**W
      IF(C(I).GT.1.0D-4) H2=((C(I)+CX(I))/2)**U
      S1X(I) =S1(I)+ DT*(K1*(TH/ROU)*H1-K2*(S1(I)+S1X(I))/2)
      S2X(I) =S2(I) + DT*K3*(TH/ROU)*H2-(K4+K5)*DT*(S2(I)+S2X(I))/2
     $+DT*K6*S3(I)
  30  CONTINUE 
  35  CONTINUE
C
C
      DO 50 I=1, NP1 
      C(I)=CX(I) 
      S1(I)=S1X(I) 
      S2(I)=S2X(I)
      S3(I)=S3(I)+DT*K5*S2(I) 
     $-DT*K6*S3(I)
  50  SIR(I)=SIR(I) + DT*KS*(TH/ROU)*C(I) 
      RETURN
      END
C
C     *****************************************************************
C     SUBROUNTINE TRIDM GIVES A SOLUTION OF A TRIDIAGONAL MATRIX-VECTOR
C     EQUATION USING THOMAS ALGORITHM
C     ***************************************************************
C
      SUBROUTINE TRIDM(A,B,C,D,N)
      IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H,O-Z)
      DIMENSION A(N),B(N),C(N),D(N)
      DO 1 I=2,N 
      C(I)=C(I)/A(I-1) 
      A(I)=A(I)-(C(I)*B(I-1))
   1  CONTINUE
      DO 2 I=2, N 
      D(I)=D(I)-(C(I)*D(I-1)) 
   2  CONTINUE
      D(N)=D(N)/A(N)
      DO 3 I=2, N
      D(N+1-I)=(D(N+1-I)-(B(N+1-I)*D(N+2-I)))/A(N+1-I)
   3  CONTINUE
      RETURN
      END
C
C     *****************************************************************
C     SUBROUNTINE INTEG PERFORMS INTEGRATION OF A TABULAR FUNCTION Y
C     GIVEN AT EQUAL DISTANCES H USING TRAPEZOIDAL RULE
C     ***************************************************************
C
      SUBROUTINE INTEG(H,Y,Z,N) 
      IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H,O-Z) 
      DIMENSION Y(N),Z(N) 
      S2=0.0D0
      IF(N-1) 40,30,10
  10  HH=H/2.0D0 
      DO 20 I=2,N
      S1=S2 
      S2=S2+HH*(Y(I)+Y(I-1)) 
  20  Z(I-1)=S1
  30  Z(N)=S2 
  40  RETURN 
      END
```

here is the input file:

```
1.  MOISTURE CONTENT,CM3/CM3             (TH) =   0.400E00
2.  BULK DENSITY,G/CM3                  (ROU) =   1.250E00
3.  COLUMN LENGTH,CM                    (COL) =   10.000E00
4.  WATER FLUX,CM/HR                   (WFLX) =   1.000E00
5.  INITIAL CONCENTRATION,MG/L           (CI) =   0.000E00
6.  CONCEN.IN INPUT PULSE, MG/L          (CS) =   10.000E00
7.  DISPERSION COEFFICIENT,D,CM2/HR       (D) =   1.000E00
8.  DISTRIB. COEFF.FOR EQL. SORP,CM3/G   (KD) =   1.000E00
9.  NONLINEAR PARAM.FOR EQUL. MECH.     (NEQ) =   1.000E00
10. FORWARD RATE REACTION, K1,HR-1       (K1) =   0.100E00
11. BACKWARD RATE REACTION, K2,HR-1      (K2) =   0.100E00
12. NONLINEAR KINETIC PARAMETER, W,       (W) =   0.500E00
13. FORWARD RATE REACTION, K3,HR-1       (K3) =   0.000E00
14. BACKWARD RATE REACTION, K4,HR-1      (K4) =   0.000E00
15. NONLINEAR KINETIC PARAMETER, U,       (U) =   0.000E00
16. IRREVERSIBLE REACTION RATE,KS,HR-1   (KS) =   0.000E00
17. FORWARD RATE REACTION, K5,HR-1       (K5) =   0.000E00
18. BACKWARD RATE REACTION, K6,HR-1      (K6) =   0.000E00
19. NUMBER OF ITERATIONS (M)             (IT) = 000
20. INPUT PULSE DURATION,HR          (TPULSE) =  12.000E00
21. TOTAL SIMULATION TIME,HR         (TTOTAL) =  16.000E00
22. PRINTOUT TIME DESIRED,HR         (TPRINT) =   4.000E00
23. INCREMENTAL TIME STEP,HR             (DT) =   0.200E00
24. INCREMENTAL DEPTH, CM                (DX) =   1.000E00
```

And the error I'm receiving:

```
Ms-MacBook-Pro-2:~ Tonoy$ gfortran mrtm.f
Ms-MacBook-Pro-2:~ Tonoy$ ./a.out
 PLEASE ENTER USER NAME (OPTIONAL):
rm
  PLEASE ENTER NAME OF SOIL (OPTIONAL):
bd
  PLEASE ENTER NAME OF SOLUTE (OPTIONAL):
cr
  ENTER DATE OR OTHER IDENTIFICATION (OPTIONAL):
2015

 --------- INPUT PARAMETERS SECTION -------------

  INPUT PARAMETERS CAN BE PROVIDED IN TWO WAYS; 
   ENTER 1 if you wish to enter the input data using
                the keyboard (i.e. interactively) 

      OR 

      ENTER 2 if an input data file is to be provided 
        PLEASE ENTER EITHER 1 OR 2
2
 PLEASE ENTER NAME OF INPUT FILE?
 (for example A:XX.DAT or C:UU.DAT for hard disk)
input.DAT
PLEASE ENTER NAME OF THE OUTPUT FILE (FOR EXAMPLE   B:ZZ.DAT)
At line 173 of file mrtm.f (unit = 5, file = 'input.DAT')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x10c688729
#1  0x10c6893f5
#2  0x10c689b59
#3  0x10c751f8b
#4  0x10c752527
#5  0x10c74f5c3
#6  0x10c7545b4
#7  0x10c679590
#8  0x10c67b2a0
Ms-MacBook-Pro-2:~ Tonoy$
```

The expected outcome given the input should give (first 8 hr out of 16 hr):
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should use some debugging flags to get a meaningful error message `-g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all`

Comment: The code should be in the question itself, a link to your google drive is not acceptable. The code must be available with the question in future years for future readers. The same holds for the input data. I am not going to download any code from external links.

Comment: @VladimirF updated!

Comment: If you change the `5`s that appear in the `open` and `read` statements to, say, `15`, what happens?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov what happens in your linux machine?? does it run??

Comment: @francescalus still get the error -doesn't help!

Comment: @VladimirF your debugging code has bug in its expression

Comment: What bug? And how doesn't francescalus' adcice help? Please be specific.

Comment: Apart from the problem of unit number 5, and it seems (to me) that the contents of the read and format statements for "input.dat" do not precisely correspond to the contents of the input.dat file given... (for example, "READ(5,700) TH,ROU,COL,WFLX" reads four variables at the same time, and the format 700 has a wrong number of spaces (50X) to be skipped). We could pass "input.dat" from stdin (on the same footing with other parameters), but to do so, we need to pass each value of the parameters without any "annotation (comment)" in the input.dat file for each parameter...

Comment: Even worse, it also seems (to me!) that the lines for setting the default values for DX and DT (e.g.., "XIN=1.00" right after "A default value of DX=1.00 is given") always set DX to an uninitialized value of DXX, resulting in an incorrect value for N=INT(COL/DX). On my computer, this resulted in segmentation fault, precisely as in the answer of @DmitriChubarov. This seems to me a bug of the original code for mixing input methods 1 and 2. So you might need to fix the code to some extent ... (I gave up at this stage, but the modification is pretty straight, only the part to read "input.dat").

Comment: @roygvib thanks for your insight! could you please explain a little more (perhaps with example) because I have little knowledge of fortran. Also, I don't mind if one of the two input systems from the fortran code is wiped out if that resolves the issue of fragmentation error.

Comment: @ToNoY I have tried a bit more (after fixing the input handling), but still the program is generating only zeros in the output, so the result is different from your expected output (assuming that the values of the input is correct). So I got stuck here... Hope someone familiar with this program will help (it might be useful to ask the author(s) of this code directly, if possible).

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the parameters in "input.dat" do not actually fall within the suggested range shown in the program (e.g., some parameters are simply zero), so you might need other values of the parameters (not sure at all). FYI, I have modified the code as in this pastebin pages ([code](http://pastebin.com/CKUaEyAF) and [input.dat](http://pastebin.com/B5JSmwgn)). So again, I essentially give up... sorry ><

Comment: @roygvib no problem, thanks for trying - I'll try to contact the creator of the script.

Answer (score 0):

In FORTRAN convention on Unix machines Unit 5 is connected to Standard Input when the program stats.

The statement on line 45

```
OPEN(5,FILE=FNAMEI)
```

happens to disconnect standard input and attaches an input file to standard input so that subsequent `READ(*,FORMAT)` statements try to read from this file and encounter its end. This causes the Input/output error you report.

If you follow the suggestion [given by *francescalus*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810208/fortran-runtime-error-for-an-input-dat-file/40815195#comment68842903_40810208) in the comments, and replace Unit 5 on lines 45 and 48-56 with Unit 15, this error will be gone.

If you compile with the options [suggested by *Vladimir*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810208/fortran-runtime-error-for-an-input-dat-file/40815195#comment68840975_40810208), i.e.

```
gfortran -Wall -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all mrtm.for -o mrtm
```

the program runs to completion and produces some output.

```
:~> ./mrtm 
 PLEASE ENTER USER NAME (OPTIONAL):
rm
  PLEASE ENTER NAME OF SOIL (OPTIONAL):
bd
  PLEASE ENTER NAME OF SOLUTE (OPTIONAL):
cr
  ENTER DATE OR OTHER IDENTIFICATION (OPTIONAL):
2015

 --------- INPUT PARAMETERS SECTION -------------

  INPUT PARAMETERS CAN BE PROVIDED IN TWO WAYS; 
   ENTER 1 if you wish to enter the input data using
                the keyboard (i.e. interactively) 

      OR 

      ENTER 2 if an input data file is to be provided 
        PLEASE ENTER EITHER 1 OR 2
2
 PLEASE ENTER NAME OF INPUT FILE?
 (for example A:XX.DAT or C:UU.DAT for hard disk)
input.dat
PLEASE ENTER NAME OF THE OUTPUT FILE (FOR EXAMPLE   B:ZZ.DAT)
zz.dat
```

Without `-fcheck=all` the program fails with `Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference` on line 253.

Comment: thank you! still wondering why the outcome is so different from what is expected. see my edits

Comment: @ToNoY check out the comments by Roy (@roygvib) to your original post.