# gfortran produce error when read from a txt file

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm a beginner with Fortran and I'm trying to code a simple program in Fortran using Eclipse. The idea is to read two integer numbers from a .txt file, then write their summation on other .txt file and save it. The codes were compiled and run sucessfully in Eclipse, however when I run its executable file, it produces this error:

```
At line 6 of file ../Alo.f95 (unit = 11, file = 'SumData3.txt')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x108c17579
#1  0x108c18235
#2  0x108c18999
#3  0x108ce001b
#4  0x108cdaa39
#5  0x108c10c73
#6  0x108c10e2a
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

Here are my codes

```
program test_random_number
implicit none
    integer :: x,y,z
    open(unit=11, file="SumData3.txt",status='old')
    read(11,*) x,y
    close(11)
    z = x+y
    open(unit=12, file="SumData4.txt")
    write(12,*) "Summation =", z
    close(12)
end
```

Could you please help me?
Thank you alot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting fortran runtime error: end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584283/getting-fortran-runtime-error-end-of-file)

Comment: Hello, this is probably a duplicate. Can you check the answer I have linked to? The important part is to check that your program actually executes in the directory where the file `SumData3.txt` is located.

Comment: If the file is missing, gfortran gives message: At line 4 of file x.f90 (unit = 11, file = '�n���*')
Fortran runtime error: File 'SumData3.txt' does not exist, the error is runtime dependent?

Comment: Have a look at the `IOSTAT` attribute of the open statement and see what it reports. Also show the content of the `SumData3.txt` file (at least the beginning). Compile with debugging options (-g) so you get some more information. Is the code the same as from the error message (looks like there is a line number difference).

Comment: Dear Albert, thank you for your response. I already check with IOSTAT and it give 0 error. The content of the file 'Sumdata3.txt' is simple with only two numbers in one row separated by a blank. Could you please tell me more how to Compile with debugging option (-g)? I'm using Fortran in Eclipse with a MacOX computer.